# How to get the pixel indices from the world coordinates with a calibrated camera in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst

I have calibrated my camera and I have now cameraParams, rotation and translation matrices (R ,t) 
I know that there is a way to get the world coordinates from the pixel indices by the function "pointsToWorld(__)" but I want to do the otherwise , I can't find anything about that in the Matlab help !
So I don't know what to do, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have to do that yourself. If you have `R` and `t`, you can use the `cameraMatrix` function to compute the camera projection matrix `P`. Then you can compute the projection of a world point into the image as follows:

```
P = cameraMatrix(cameraParams, R, t);
p = [X, Y, Z, 1] * P;
x = p(1) / p(3);
y = p(2) / p(3);
```

`X`, `Y`, and `Z` are the world coordinates. `x` and `y` are the image coordinates in pixels.